# Rules behaviour in Mathematica and length of initial list

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, rules

consider the following:

```
    rule={x_, y_} -> {y, x};

    {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} /. rule
    {{a, b}, {c, d}} /. rule
    {{a, b}} /. {x_, y_} -> rule
```

the output is:

```
{{b, a}, {d, c}, {f, e}}
{{c, d}, {a, b}}
{{b, a}}
```

Suppose however that the length of the initial list is not known. how should I rewrite my rule so that the individual elements in the sublists are reversed, regardless of the length of the input list ie when the length is 2

Comment: I think you want something like this: Replace[lists, rule, {2}].  It'll only try to apply the rule at level 2.

Answer (score 3):

First it should be noted that this specific operation is better done with `Reverse[x, {2}]`:

```
Reverse[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{b, a}, {d, c}, {f, e}}
> ```

That said, for replacement rules you should use either `Replace` with a *levelspec* (third argument) rather than `ReplaceAll`, or restrict your pattern such that it will only match on the elements you intend.  (Additionally, remember to use `:>` instead of `->` when using named patterns to properly localize these symbols.)

```
Replace[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {x_, y_} :> {y, x}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{b, a}, {d, c}}
> ```

Examples of restricted pattern that will work with `/.` on your sample:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}} /. {x : Except[_List], y_} :> {y, x}

{{a, b}, {c, d}} /. {x_Symbol, y_} :> {y, x}

{{a, b}, {c, d}} /. {x_, y_?AtomQ} :> {y, x}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive way:

```
ClearAll[rule1]

rule1 = {z_, y___} :> {z /. x_List :> Reverse[x], Sequence @@ ({y} /. rule1)}
```

Which results:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, 2, {1, {2, 3}}, 4, head[x]} /. rule1

Out[]= {{3, 2, 1}, 2, {{2, 3}, 1}, 4, head[x]}
```

Although you may as well do this instead:

```
ClearAll[rule2]

rule2 = x_List :> (# /. z_List :> Reverse[z] &) /@ x
```

Alternatively, just

```
rule3 = x_List :> Reverse /@ x
```

will work as well if you know beforehand that all the elements of your list are lists.